# How to convert JScrollPane like JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have to change `JScrollPane` to something like `JLabel`. I used this code here:

```
myJScroll.setBorder(null);
myJScroll.setEnabled(false);
myJScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
myJScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

But with `setEnable(false)`, it has another color that covers this pane.

How can I change this color to another color?

Comment: The enabled colouring is generally provided by the UI delegate, you might be able to change the color key in `UIManager`, but, conceptually a `JScrollPane` and a `JLabel` are two entirely different things, `JLabel` is transparent for a start

Comment: Thanks, On the special case, I need to use the JScrollPane

Comment: So.. you're trying to create a scroll pane that ..doesn't look ***or*** act like a scroll pane?  How useless would *that* be?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I use  myJScroll.setBackgroundColor(Color.white); to set background color, it works properly, but the color text on jscrollpane changes from Black color to Gray color. I use setForeground(Color.BLACK) set Black color again, but it does not work..Please give me advise...Thanks

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo `JScrollPane` doesn't have text...also, why would you need to disable it? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

A `JScrollPane` contains a `Viewport` component that is opaque by default. You can set a custom background color for the `Viewport`:

`myJScroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLUE);`

or make the viewport non-opaque:

`myJScroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);`

and depending on your needs, you may also want to make the `JScrollPane` non-opaque (to get the true background color of the parent component of the scrollpane:

`myJScroll.setOpaque(false);`

Also keep in mind the opacity and default background color of the component that is being added to the viewport.

For instance, try this as a test case:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ScrollPaneTest extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ScrollPaneTest()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel myScrolledComponent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myScrolledComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        myScrolledComponent.setOpaque(false);
        myScrolledComponent.add(new JLabel("Some text"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollPane myJScroll = new JScrollPane(myScrolledComponent);
        myJScroll.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        myJScroll.setOpaque(false);

        myJScroll.setBorder(null);
        myJScroll.setEnabled(false);
        myJScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        myJScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        myJScroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        myJScroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

        super.add(myJScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        ScrollPaneTest test = new ScrollPaneTest();
        test.setBackground(Color.RED);
        f.add(test);
        f.pack();
        f.show();
    }
}
```

The above class will display the `JLabel` text with a red background (transparent all the way to the `ScrollPaneTest` component.

A second example based on your comment:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ScrollPaneTest2 extends JScrollPane
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ScrollPaneTest2()
    {
        super();
        super.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        super.getViewport().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        super.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

        return;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        ScrollPaneTest2 scrollPane = new ScrollPaneTest2();
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
        f.add(scrollPane);

        JPanel myScrolledComponent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myScrolledComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        myScrolledComponent.setOpaque(false);
        myScrolledComponent.add(new JLabel("Some text"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        scrollPane.getViewport().setView(myScrolledComponent);

        scrollPane.setBorder(null);
        scrollPane.setEnabled(false);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        f.pack();
        f.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo The best way I've found to determine which component's background is being displayed is to set all components involved to opaque, and set a starkly different background color for each component.

Comment: the JScrollPaneTest extends from JScrollPane, not Jpane.

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo Please see my revised answer for a second example extending JScrollPane.